# Using an Alphabet as a Matplotlib marker

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker

How to plot an Alphabet (eg the letter 'y') as a `matplotlib` marker?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make custom markers with [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html#custom-markers-with-mathtext).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

markers = ["$x$","$y$","$z$"]

ax = plt.gca()
for i, m in enumerate(markers):
    ax.plot((i+1)*[i,i+1],marker=m,lw=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]